# Alphabetical c++ sort without sort keyword

Tags: c++

I am making a sorting algorithm only using variable assignment. The first do while loop validates the number of students inputted and cannot be above 25. The second half is a while loop which sorts the names. The final output will only display the first name and the last name alphabetically. I cannot figure out why the code only displays the last name alphabetically and not the first. Any thoughts or input would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double stunum = 1;
    int error;

    do {
        error = 0;
        cout << "Please enter the number of students" << endl;
        cin >> stunum;
        if (stunum < 1 || stunum > 25)
        {
            cout << "Please enter a valid integer" << endl;
            error = 1;
            system("pause"); system("cls");
        }  
    } while (error == 1);

    //Declaration 
    string nameFirst;
    string nameLast;
    string nameInitial;
    double iteration = 1;

    //Sort / Input
    while (iteration <= stunum)
    {
        cout << "Enter the name of student " << iteration << endl;
        cin >> nameInitial;

        if (nameInitial > nameLast)
        {
            nameLast = nameInitial;
        }

        if (nameInitial < nameFirst)
        {
            nameFirst = nameInitial;
        }

        iteration++;
    }
    
    //Display
    cout << "The student with the highest name alphabetically is " << nameFirst << endl;
    cout << "The student with the lowest name alphabetically is " << nameLast << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try std::string::compare: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Comment: Because `nameInitial < nameFirst` is never true, when `nameFirst` is the empty string.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean, is there something I could assign the variable to?

Comment: Thank you @Olha, I would love to however I am writing it for a class and can only use variable declaration and loops

Comment: There is no `sort` keyword in C++.

Comment: not the problem, but `stunum` should be integer not a `double`. This potentially leads to subtle bugs when you use it in loop conditions as eg in `while (iteration <= stunum)`

Comment: @JackCaugherty One way would be to set it to `"zzzzzzzz"` or something. But a better way is to treat the first string you read specially. Use the first string to set the initial values of `nameFirst` and `nameLast` only from the second string onwards should you do the comparisons that you are currently doing.

Comment: You're not sorting any names. To sort names, you have to actually store all of them in an array or vector, and then actually sort them. You're just keeping track of which one is the biggest but losing the rest.